# How is data provided in oauth2?

Tags: oauth2

Can a connected app query and crud on the tables created by a sales force app in sales force db, using oauth scope as full? Or tables created by an app belong to that app only and other app can't access it. What is the default configuration.
P.S. not really a sf dev, but trying to understand whether oauth2 scopes work same in sf as everywhere. Pardon me if I'm missing something obvious that you blokes know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we define the connect app in Salesforce we give the value of Scope.
'Selected OAuth Scopes' control the types of resources that the client application can access in a Salesforce organization.

[image]

Supported values are:

- api - Allows access to the current, logged-in user’s account over the APIs, such as the REST API or Bulk API. This value also includes chatter_api, which allows access to Chatter REST API resources.
- chatter_api - Allows access to only the Chatter REST API resources.
- full - Allows access to all data accessible by the current, logged-in user. full does not return a refresh token. You must explicitly request the refresh_token scope to get a refresh token.
- id - Allows access to the Identity Service. You can request profile, email, address, or phone, individually to get the same result as using id; they are all synonymous.
- openid - Allows access to the current, logged in user’s unique identifier for OpenID Connect apps. The openid scope can be used in the user-agent flow and the web server flow to get back a signed ID token conforming to the OpenID Connect specifications in addition to the access token.
- refresh_token - Allows a refresh token to be returned if you are eligible to receive one, and is synonymous with requesting offline_access.
  visualforce - Allows access to Visualforce pages.
- web - Allows the ability to use the access_token on the Web. This also includes visualforce, allowing access to Visualforce pages.

If we give permission of API then the Authenticated user can access all the API(Salesforce table or DB) which the original user has access.

He can access/modify all the data which original user can access and can perform any action on behalf of him. Yes oauth2 scopes work same in SF as everywhere

You can read about it in detail here [Digging Deeper into OAuth 2.0 on Force.com](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Digging_Deeper_into_OAuth_2.0_on_Force.com)